# pandoc: unrecognized option `lua-filter` pandoc --lua-filter test.lua test.md

Tags: filter, pandoc

I solved this problem.  Took the advise of the person who suggested "ask Ubuntu"

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084723/issues-installing-pandoc-2-3-1-in-ubuntu-18-04-1

```
whereis pandoc
```

It was installed by conda when I installed spyder.

```
conda update pandoc

$ pandoc --lua-filter wordcount.lua resume.md
1112 words in body
```

I am just started to write filters for processing my resume.  Unfortunately
what appears to be exactly the command listed on the pandoc tutorial
doesn't work for me.  https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html
I must be missing something.

The code is

```
$ pandoc --lua-filter wordcount.lua resume.md

pandoc: unrecognized option `--lua-filter'
Try pandoc --help for more information.
```

Here is my version of pandoc:

```
$ pandoc --version
    pandoc 1.19.2.1
    Compiled with pandoc-types 1.17.0.4, texmath 0.9, skylighting 0.1.1.4
    Default user data directory: /home/harlan/.pandoc
    Copyright (C) 2006-2016 John MacFarlane
    Web:  http://pandoc.org
    This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
    There is no warranty, not even for merchantability or fitness
    for a particular purpose.
```

I took the advice below in the comment, but it did not change my pandoc version:

```
harlan@harlan-MS-7976:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install -f ./pandoc-2.4-1-amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'pandoc' instead of './pandoc-2.4-1-amd64.deb'
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  pandoc
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 301 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/17.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 133 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 /home/harlan/Downloads/pandoc-2.4-1-amd64.deb pandoc amd64 2.4-1 [17.0 MB]
Selecting previously unselected package pandoc.
(Reading database ... 407228 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../pandoc-2.4-1-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pandoc (2.4-1) ...
Setting up pandoc (2.4-1) ...
harlan@harlan-MS-7976:~/Downloads$ pandoc --version
pandoc 1.19.2.1
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.17.0.4, texmath 0.9, skylighting 0.1.1.4
Default user data directory: /home/harlan/.pandoc
Copyright (C) 2006-2016 John MacFarlane
Web:  http://pandoc.org
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is no warranty, not even for merchantability or fitness
for a particular purpose.
```

Comment: Get the newest pandoc version from https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases

Comment: I did the but the problem was not resolved.

Comment: `apt-get` doesn't install the newest version. the version in the debian repository is quite old. uninstall that and download the `.deb` file from https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases

Comment: I did download that file and used the -f option of apt-get to install it.  This is shown in the edit to my question.  The version number did not change.

Comment: probably first need to uninstall the old version... otherwise ask on https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Note, selecting 'pandoc' instead of './pandoc-2.4-1-amd64.deb'